# Has a non-human ever attended any Wizarding school?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

At least from the movies, we can gather that all the students and faculty at Hogwarts are human, but the Potterverse is full of other magical creatures, some of which interact peacefully with humans. **Has any other race of beings ever attended any of the Wizarding schools around the world? If so, who, where, and when?**

Comment: Does a one-quarter Veela count?

Comment: Wasn't Hagrid also a student at Hogwarts, though he later got expelled (and later became a teacher there)? As I recall, he's at least part giant...

Comment: @sumelic Is Hagrid *half-giant*, and not a really tall guy?

Comment: @sumelic Who was the centaur?

Comment: If a werewolf counts, Remus Lupin attended Hogwarts.

Comment: @Bellatrix I believe a werewolf is just a human with lycanthropy.

Comment: @WilliamJackson I would say so, but I'm mentioning it because I don't know what OP would consider other beings, and they might find it helpful.

Comment: @Bellatrix I don't think that would count, but I do find it helpful

Comment: @SonOfSam Cool! :)

Comment: Assuming that you're asking about non-humans rather than part-humans, I don't think any non-humans are allowed to use wands, so there'd be no point in sending them to school.

Comment: You say "all the students and faculty at Hogwarts are human," but you overlook the ghost history teacher. (Unless that counts as human?)

Comment: "At least from the movies, we can gather that all the students and faculty at Hogwarts are human" For starters, [Flitwick](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/565QwwST7iCYCKCQqoQwqU/b1783711fe4bb63bf3b6607761a2a94f/FiliusFlitwick_WB_F1_FlitwickStandingOnBook_Promo_080615_Port.jpg?w=1200) wasn't. Also, you are assuming that regular wizards are human, which is... debatable.

Comment: Does it count that a squib made it as far as the Sorting Ceremony?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are a few examples of students that are not full-blood human attending a school of magic.

#### Rubeus Hagrid

Half-giant, attended Hogwarts.

#### Fleur Delacour

Quarter-Veela, attended Beauxbatons. We can safely assume her sister, **Gabrielle Delacour**, also attended Beauxbatons.

#### Filius Flitwick

Part-goblin (several generations removed), attended Hogwarts

---

If you move beyond students to school staff as well, you can include:

#### Firenze

Centuar, Divination teach at Hogwarts. The only non-part-human on this list!

#### Olympe Maxime

Half-giant, headmistress at Beauxbatons.

---

Several people have asked if Remus Lupin, a werewolf, should be on this list. He doesn't count because a werewolf is a human suffering from a condition called *lycanthropy*. A werewolf is a human, just as a person with cancer is a human.

Another situation worth mentioning is the ghost Professor Binns. Does a human cease to be a human after he dies? Does he transform from a human *being* to a human *been*?

Comment: Thinking about the staff at Hogwarts, I ask myself, "Is a ghost human?"

Comment: Has a ghost ever taught at or attended a school?

Comment: @SonOfSam Professor Binns.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure what to do with that

Comment: I believe Firenze actually was part-human.  The top part, to be precise.

Comment: @jwodder: That's just in appearance. Even though Umbridge refers to centaurs and mermaids as "half-breeds", it seems to be just a slur. Firenze certainly is never implied to have any human ancestry, and I don't think it is even made clear whether centaurs and humans can interbreed in the world of Harry Potter (centaurs are referred to as a separate species, which by some definitions would imply "no", but I think so are giants, goblins and veela, who are all established to be reproductively compatible with humans).

Comment: @sumelic I'm pretty sure he was joking...

Comment: Would a Werewolf also count as non-full human, and therefore allow Lupin to make the list?

Comment: @gabe3886 No. Werewolves are humans with lycanthropy.

Comment: JKR actually told that she never imagined Flitwick to be non-human, she always thought of him as of a very short man. It's the movies that gave him goblin ancestors.

Comment: Yes, the house elves. Though I guess it depends on what you mean by "attend".

Answer (score 12):

## They can’t in Britain - they can’t get wands.

In Britain at least, it’s very unlikely that any pure non-human (rather than a part-non-human, like Hagrid) could attend Hogwarts. All students are required to have purchased a wand before they start at Hogwarts.

> “Other Equipment
>
> *1 wand*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5 (Diagon Alley)*</sup></sub>

No non-human creatures are allowed to use or carry a wand, so they wouldn’t be able to own and use one to attend Hogwarts with.

> “Come off it, Amos,’ said Mr Weasley quietly, ‘you don’t seriously think it was the elf? **The Dark Mark’s a wizard’s sign. It requires a wand.**’
>
> ‘Yeah,’ said Mr Diggory, ‘and she *had* a wand.’
>
> *‘What?’* said Mr Weasley.
>
> ‘Here, look.’ Mr Diggory held up a wand and showed it to Mr Weasley. ‘Had it in her hand. So that’s clause three of the Code of Wand Use broken for a start. *No non-human creature is permitted to carry or use a wand.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9 (The Dark Mark)*</sup></sub>

It’s unclear if this law is in effect in other countries as well or if it’s specifically a British law, but certainly in Britain, purely non-human creatures wouldn’t be able to attend Hogwarts, since they’d require a wand but it’s illegal for them to have or use a wand. This may be different in other countries, though, so it’s still possible that purely non-human creatures have attended some of the other wizarding schools.

Answer (score -4):

### Possibly Voldemort, according to Hagrid.

According to Hagrid in Chapter Four of *Philosopher's Stone*, Voldemort might not be human:

> "Some say he died. Codswallop, in my opinion. Dunno if he had enough human left in him to die.

It's unclear exactly when Voldemort would have become non-human. He had already begun using Dark Magic, and he had already murdered, while yet a student. Dumbledore in Chapter Twenty-Three of *Half-Blood Prince* seems to have associated the dehumanization with creating Horcruxes:

> And I thought I knew what that meant, though the Death Eaters did not. He was referring to his Horcruxes, Horcruxes in the plural, Harry, which I don’t believe any other wizard has ever had. Yet it fitted: Lord Voldomort has seemed to grow less human with the passing years, and the transformation he had undergone seemed to me to be only explainable if his soul was mutilated beyond the realms of what we might call 'usual evil'..."

In any case, by the time of *Philosopher's Stone* he was certainly already at the point Hagrid referred to, and he then spent a year attending Hogwarts attached to Professor Quirrel.

([Note that the idea that Voldemort might not be human can also be used to explain other things.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/203969/100430))

### Possibly Quirrel, according to Harry.

In Chapter Eight of *Prisoner of Azkaban* we have the following passage (my emphasis):

> Harry stared. Not only was this the last answer he'd expected, but Lupin had said Voldemort's name. The only **person** Harry had ever heard say the name aloud (apart from himself) was Professor Dumbledore.

Yet in Chapter Seventeen of *Phlosopher's Stone* Quirrel says "Voldemort" a couple of times:

> Tried to frighten me — as though he could, when I had Lord Voldemort on my side...."

> Lord Voldemort showed me how wrong I was.

Perhaps, then, Quirrel was not a person (perhaps because he was hosting Voldemort), yet he attended Hogwarts.

(To be fair, Harry also heard Hagrid say "Voldemort" in *Philosopher's Stone*, but Hagrid is already mentioned in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158521/100430).)

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think Voldemort actually transformed into *another race* other than human. He was losing his *spiritual* humanity (or mental or emotional), rather than his physical humanity. However, we're told there was a physical aspect to this, so I suppose it's *possible* he was in the process of transforming into something else. If so, I would think that would be something demonic, personally, if anything specific.

Comment: @RDFozz I agree he didn't transform into another race. But Hagrid, at least, seemed to think that Voldemort lacked humanity in the sense that he couldn't be physically killed.

Comment: @Alex - Have to agree with RDFozz. He may have lost his (metaphorical) humanity during his school years but his transformation didn't start until more than a decade after he'd left, and even then he was a disfigured human, not some other species.

Comment: @Valorum Indeed, I noted in the answer that Dumbledore's words implies that Voldemort became non-human after his school years. However, it satisfies the criteria of this question because as I noted in the last sentence (not counting the parenthetical link) Voldemort attended Hogwarts again many years later.

Comment: @Alex - Arriving with an army and killing students isn't "attending" school since he's not officially registered on arrival.

Comment: @Valorum I wasn’t referring to when he arrived to kill students. I was referring to the year he spent attached to Quirrel. I’d say that counts as attending. The question is did not specify that it was only talking about registered students.

Comment: @Alex - I think you're confused about the term "attendance". By this token Dobby and the other house elves also count.

Comment: I don't discount the possibility that I am confused. But I did look up the definition of "attend" and [the first definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attend) was "to be present at", "to go to". (In fact, if someone would have posted an answer identifying Dobby and the other house-elves I would probably have upvoted it for creativity in taking advantage of the vague wording of the question.